# How To Make MenuItem not Active

Tags: c++, gdi

Now I've The Edit MenuItem ... I've Created it but i need to make these options not active in order not to be pressed with no reason

```
HMENU hMenu, hSubMenu;

            hMenu = CreateMenu();

            hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
            AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_DDA, "DDA");
            AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_MID, "Mid-Point");
            AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hSubMenu, "Algorithm");

            hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
            AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_UNDO, "Undo");
            AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_REDO, "Redo");
            AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hSubMenu, "Edit");

            SetMenu(hwnd, hMenu);
```

is there a flag or function to be called to set the Submenu item active or inactive according to the usage of the Submenu item ??

Answer (score 1):

You can include the MF_GRAYED flag to disable a menu item.